# Increasing/Decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, functions

What would be an example of a function that is bijective, but is neither increasing or decreasing?
I know a constant function is neither increasing or decreasing, would you just have to choose a domain/range to make it bijective?

Comment: Let $S = \{a\}$ and define $f:S\to S$ by $f(a)=a$. Then $f$ is bijective but there is no order relation on $S$ so clearly $f$ is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: Are you interested continuous bijective functions? If yes then the answer is negative. Their is no example because all continuous bijective functions are either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing

Comment: How about $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ defined by $f(1)=3,f(2)=2,f(3)=4,f(4)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example with domain and range equal to $\mathbb R$ take $f(x)=x$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=2x$ for $x$ irrational.

Note that if $x$ is an irrational number in $(\frac 1  2,1)$ and $y=1$ then $x<y$ but $f(x) >f(y)$.

[If a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ is one-to-one then it is strictly monotonic].